# Firebase: how to create nested object

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

There are questions on how to update nested properties for a Firebase record, but no answers on how to create records with nested properties.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784702/updating-nested-objects-firebase) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355535/creating-nested-array-in-firebase-object) were similar but did not help.

From the web, the goal is to create a Firebase record with nested properties.

Using dot notation works for updates, but a nested hierarchy doesn't get created when reusing the same key for creating the record.

Which makes sense because the key doesn't impart any information about the data types of the child properties.

What is the right way to create an object with nested properties?

```
async test(serviceId, numCredits, emailAddress) {
    // Set credits key.
    let creditsKey = `credits.${serviceId}.numAllowed`;

    try {
        // Get user matching @emailAddress.
        let user = await this.getUser(emailAddress);

        // New user? Create database record.
        if (!user) {
            this.db_
                    .collection('users')
                    .add(
                        {
                            emailAddress: emailAddress,
                            [{creditsKey}]: numCredits
                        }
            );

        // Nope, user exists so update his/her record.
        } else {
            // Set update query.
            let query = this.db_
                                    .collection('users')
                                    .where('emailAddress', '==', emailAddress);

            // Run update query.
            const querySnapshot = await query.get();
            return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
               [creditsKey]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(numCredits)
            });
        }
    } catch(e) {
        debug('Error in test(): ' + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, the following would do the trick. (There are probably more elegant solutions however...)

```
  const obj = {};
  obj.numAllowed = numCredits;
  const obj1 = {};
  obj1[serviceId] = obj;

  // ...

  this.db_.collection('users')
     .add(
         {
            emailAddress: emailAddress,
            credits: obj1
         })
```

Comment: we couldn't find a more elegant solution, and this is what we wound up doing as well. thanks for your help!